# How to configure the Brand Settings in Epic Games DEV-Portal correctly? Website + private policy

Tags: game-development, unreal-engine5, privacy-policy

I hope you are doing well. I have a question regarding Unreal Engine EOS because I want to set it up in my brand settings on the Epic Games Dev Portal. I want everyone to be able to sign in to my game with their account and not just the developers. I need to provide a URL to my website and my privacy policy (see image). But what does the page need to include? Is it enough if the page consists only of simple text with the privacy policy? Do I need to include information about myself such as an imprint, etc.? And where can I get a privacy policy? What are your experiences...? Thank you for any help.[image]

Comment: This is the wrong Stack for this type of question as its not about programming and has no code to fix.  That being said, there are tons of templates that exist on the web, however f you want to do it right, find a cheap lawyer to certify some of things you are claiming in it.